# Destructor-like for a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

Is there something similar to a destructor, but for a `namespace`? I have several namespaces that, each, have some specific functionality, and some have their own, particular variables inside. I understand that defining those variables as `static` will limit their scope to the particular use of the namespace, e.g. calling `NamespaceA::function()`, but will they be destroyed (deleted, cleared, etc) somehow when I call `NamespaceB::function()`?

As in, I call `NamespaceA::function()` and `NamespaceA::vector` gets used, then I need to call `NamespaceB::function()`, and its `NamespaceB::vector` gets used. Now I have two vectors taking up memory, when I only need one, for the current namespace. Is there a way i can clear up automatically the unused variables, similar to what a destructor does in a class? Note that calling namespaces is at the user's whim, it's not known which class gets called, and when.

The reason I want this is that there may be vectors that I don't want hanging around uselessly, eating up memory, even if they aren't `GB` worth of data.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it is difficult to tell but if you have global variables declared inside a namespace they are just like regular global variables except the name is scoped.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thta is bad news, then. I understand using global variables is not a good practise, so I'd like to avoid that. But, for the sake of the answer, do namespaces have something like a destructor, or some kind?

Comment: Namespaces are purely syntactic constructs used to organize your code. Namespaces are not "constructed" at runtime and therefore cannot have a destructor or anything similar to it. Variables declared inside namespace are namely static variables that are only visible within the given scope.

Comment: No.  A namespace is just a way to add a extra scope to a variable/function/type so you can use the same name.

Comment: I see, thank you both for the answers. I think my only choice now is a class, then.

Comment: The solution to your problem may lie in not using `NamespaceA::vector` or `NamespaceB::vector`. Can you reorganize your code such that the `vector` is created by the client code and passed to other functions?

Comment: @RSahu I might be able to do that, but it implies the client handling all the variables that all the namespaces have. One solution is in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't such language construct in c++, like a `namespace` wide destructor.

The option you have is to use special functions in your `namespace` that are used to initialize and freeing occupied resources held as global variables in the `namespace` explicitly:

```
namespace Mine {
    A* someGlobalResource = nullptr;

    void init() {
         someGlobalResource = new A();
    }
    void freeResources() {
         delete someGlobalResource;
         someGlobalResource = nullptr;
    }
}

int main() {
    Mine::init();

    // Do works

    Mine::freeResources();
}
```

---

Another solution is of course to create a helper class in your namespace doing that and hide these function calls in a constructor/destructor:

Header:

```
namespace Mine {
    class MyNameSpace {
    public:
         MyNameSpace();
         ~MyNameSpace();
    private:
         static std::atomic<bool> initialized = false;
    };
}
```

Translation unit:

```
namespace { // Hide the functions in an anonymous namespace
    void init() {
         someGlobalResource = new A();
    }
    void freeResources() {
         delete someGlobalResource;
         someGlobalResource = nullptr;
    }

    A* someGlobalResource = nullptr;
}

namespace Mine {
     MyNameSpace::MyNameSpace() {
         if(!initialized) {
             MyNameSpace::init();
         }
     }
     MyNameSpace::~MyNameSpace() {
         freeResources();
     }
}
```

and use it like

```
int main() {
    Mine::MyNameSpace initHelper;

    // Do works
} // initHelper's destructor is called here
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, but if I am to go there, I think I'll just make a class and let the destructor work for me (or the user).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I extended my answer a bit regarding that. Generally I would not recommend using global resources (namespace or not) in designs.

Comment: That's what I want to avoid, too. I thought using `static` will limit the cope, but NathanOliver cleared that up. So it's either a class for each, or an interface class, which will have all the needed variables, but the variables would only be used once per call.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen You're probably asking about a XY-problem. Consider to reorganize your design using interfaces.